# How to assign an overloaded class method to anonymous method?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, we can assign a class method (declared as `procedure of object`) as parameter of type anonymous method.

For overloaded methods (same method names), passing the object method fail with compilation error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Project56.dpr(40): E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.SysUtils.TProc<System.Integer,System.Integer>' and 'Procedure of object'
```

The following example show the situation.  Is that possible to let the overloaded method pass as anonymous method parameter?

```
type
  TTest = class
  public
    procedure M(a: Integer); overload;
    procedure M(a, b: Integer); overload;
  end;

procedure TTest.M(a, b: Integer);
begin
  WriteLn(a, b);
end;

procedure TTest.M(a: Integer);
begin
  WriteLn(a);
end;

procedure DoTask1(Proc: TProc<Integer>);
begin
  Proc(100);
end;

procedure DoTask2(Proc: TProc<Integer,Integer>);
begin
  Proc(100, 200);
end;

begin
  var o := TTest.Create;
  DoTask1(o.M);  // <-- Success
  DoTask2(o.M);  // <-- Fail to compile: E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.SysUtils.TProc<System.Integer,System.Integer>' and 'Procedure of object'
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 17):

When you write

```
DoTask2(o.M);
```

The compiler sees that `o.M` is not an anonymous method, and generates one for you behind the scenes, that wraps the call to `o.M`. Unfortunately it's not able to search overloaded methods when doing this, hence the compile error.

The solution is to manually generate the anonymous method wrapper.

```
DoTask2(
  procedure(a, b: Integer) 
  begin
    o.M(a, b);
  end 
);
```

This is exactly what the compiler is doing for you behind the scenes when it wraps a standard method with an anonymous method. So whilst the syntax is tiresome, the end result is identical at runtime.